# Milvus multiple vectors in a row

Tags: milvus, vector-database

Is it possible to have multiple vectors in a row on milvus. What is needed is a custom score that is like a weighted average of the individual vector scores. Is there a limit on the number of vectors we can have on milvus? If not possible on milvus, any other open source vector db with this facility? Possible to index all vector columns?

Thanks

Comment: why not just create a custom vector generator that uses your vectors to create a weighted average?